# How do I login protect a static html page in node/react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes

Newer to node and react.  So I have a static html page.  The react on the prod server is run by nginx.  I have this route protected by a login.

```
{!guest && <Route path="/" component={Home} />}
```

Home then contains the route to the virtual path which redirects.

```
<Route path="/virtual" render={() => {window.location.href="virtualworkouts.html"}}  />
```

Someone can easily bookmark that page and circumvent the login entirely.  How can I make it truly login protected?  Something like...

```
app.get('/virtual', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/virtualworkouts.html");
});
```

Where that file is somewhere different than what nginx is serving.
Thanks!

Comment: With react-router you can load individual components. So what you could try is having one index.html file which loads your root component say App. Then App contains the react router. Then when a user requests a route the react router will respond with the required component. So essentially you have one index.html file which loads your root component. Then everything else is a JavaScript file. That way all requests can be handled by the client. Then if the server receives the request there won't be a html file to serve.

Comment: Awesome!  what would that component look like?

Comment: Here is a great article about "protected routes" - EXACTLY what you're looking for: https://seegatesite.com/implement-login-page-and-protected-route-reactjs/

Comment: That tutorial is for protecting the react trouser which is on the client side. I don’t think that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly. Somebody gets served an HTML file. If they go directly to the page they still get that file. Given that in the question you are using react-router and the file is still being served. You most likely need to check if the user is logged in on the server.

```
function isLoggedIn() {
  if (someConditionToCheckUserIsLoggedIn)
    return next();
  else
    res.redirect('/error');
}

app.get('/yourroute', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  // Code
});
```

This way if the user requests a certain page they won't receive the requested file unless they are logged in. Note the browser may still cache the file though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for!  Need to write the logic for the logged in checker!  Thanks.

Comment: How should the react route call the yourroute api call?

Comment: Here is an article where they serve a static HTML file and display the content. Note this isn't very React like but it should work. So you can use Axios or the fetch API to make your request. Once the server receives the request you can serve your HTML file. Then you can use a component to display the HTML file.

https://medium.com/@justintulk/serving-static-html-into-a-react-component-using-node-express-8cb9fc9194df